# apply mod operation to classify

Tags: machine-learning, classification, linear-regression

I have a set of data.
For the simple case:

```
value:  0,  3, 6, 8, 10, 13, 14
type:   o,  o, x, x,  x,  o,  o
```

The plan is to use a simple "threshold" to classify.
the idea is to apply mod + shift to classify better:
ex, x = x mod 12
then the set of pairs becomes

```
(value) % 12:      0, 1(13), 2(14), 3, 6, 8, 10

type:              o, o,     o,     o, x, x,  x
```

Now we can use threshold = 5 to classify without error.

Is there any formal algorithm about this kind of mod & shift classification algorithm?

Comment: It's a good idea. Why do you think that `mod` opearation is appropriate? From domain knowledge or something?

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I am a bit rusty in this area.

Some initial thoughts:

- There are [Kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method) that implicitly do something similar.
- Radial-Basis-Function kernels [RBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel) are one thing that I can think off. Or maybe just a [Polynomial Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel).
- The modulus will not work as a Kernel, since it has to be the dual (--> Kernel-trick) and has to be a bijective function. But the modulus loses information and cannot be "undone".

I forked Karpathy's [SVM-JS demo](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/svmjs/demo/) and changed the data to your example data above. This gives a very easy visualization that in your example the radial distance to a (1D-)circle centered around 8 would make for a good classifier.

[image: A hacky version of 1D data in Karpathy's tool]

But given that you want to represent the modulus, and since maybe you have also 'x' values at (6+12=) 18, 20, or 22, this reminds me of a periodic signal. And for a periodic signal, you can just transform your input data into the "Fourier Space" and classify on that. I put this in quotes, because an approximation is probably just fine.

So, let's try to make the Kernel function the (Modulus, Remainder) mapping. (Approximately analogous to Amplitude and Phase). (Side note: Googling "Fourier Transform Kernel Machine Learning" indicates that this might be a thing.)

`Phi(x) = (x mod N, x rem N)`.

As far as I can tell, this is a valid feature mapping function. And you can then apply this on an SVM.